# localhost redirecting to http://localhost.192.168.1.33.xip.io/

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, networking, localhost

I recently installed wordpress on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. In order to connect to a wordpress website locally I made some configurational changes because of that whenever I try to connect to localhost, browser directs my requests to http://localhost.192.168.1.33.xip.io/ automatically. I am not able to access my local Wordpress because of this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved. If you are using bitnami, you need to change site URL in bnconfig.

sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --machine_hostname YOURDOMANIN

For more details, please have a look at [bitnami forum](https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-to-configure-dns-or-wordpress-to-work-with-proper-domain-name/51781/2).

Good luck